# Encouraging each other to vote & edit?

Tags: discussion

Our active userbase is still quite small, but there's already a decent number of existing questions and answers.

Should we be encouraging newcomers to give a tour to existing material, editing and up-voting the stuff they find interesting in order to make it even better and more visible, and commenting or down-voting some of the less brilliant stuff? (And, if so, how?)

Answer (score 8):

I think most users here have done a good job of "voting early and voting often" as the saying goes. Editing and voting are things that users should be encouraged to do, but besides a meta post like this one, or the promise of badges, there's not much we can do to encourage users to perform these specific tasks.

It's important to remember that no matter how good the posts are on this site, it would be nothing without the users.

Comment: ...and please don't start encouraging/asking for votes in comments. It's hardly noticeable when it happens rarely, but it becomes very annoying quickly when it happens more often.